# error in pulling up results though parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to pull up results through a dropdown selection which has date range option like today, weekly, monthly, yearly

```
protected void ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime StartDate;
        DateTime? EndDate;

        if (ddlFilter.SelectedValue == "today")
        {
            //StartDate = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFilter.SelectedValue)
            StartDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate = DateTime.Today;
        }
        if (ddlFilter.SelectedValue == "weekly")
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date;
        }
        if (ddlFilter.SelectedValue == "byweekly")
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15).Date;
        }
        if (ddlFilter.SelectedValue == "monthly")
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Date;
        }
        if (ddlFilter.SelectedValue == "yearly")
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
        }
        FillGridFilter(StartDate, EndDate);
    }

private void FillGridFilter(DateTime StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
    {
        if (EndDate != null)
        {
            hdnid.Value = EndDate.ToString();
        }

        grdCrew.DataSource = null;
        DataTable dtbl = BIZ.ReportsBIZAdmin.ReportsCityFilter(StartDate, EndDate).Tables[0];

        if (dtbl != null && dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdCrew.DataSource = dtbl;
            grdCrew.DataBind();
            ViewState["griddata"] = dtbl;
        }
        else
        {
            grdCrew.DataSource = null;
            grdCrew.DataBind();
            ViewState["griddata"] = null;
        }
    }
```

now its giing me error on `"FillGridFilter(StartDate, EndDate);"` says `Use of unassigned local variable 'EndDate`' and `Use of unassigned local variable 'EndDate'`

and

```
DataTable dtbl = BIZ.ReportsBIZAdmin.ReportsCityFilter(StartDate, EndDate).Tables[0];
```

says `The best overloaded method match for 'BIZ.ReportsBIZAdmin.ReportsCityFilter(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments`

stored procedure seems to be working fine, it is:

```
if @end_date = 'today' 
begin
    select jp.id, city.name[City]

    from rs_job_posting jp

    inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
    inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
    inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id

    where posting_date between '@start_date' and '@end_date'
    order by no_of_posts Desc 
END
```

Comment: Is the question mark a typo? `private void FillGridFilter(DateTime StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)`

Comment: I never knew you could do that. Learnt something new again :)

Comment: what do u mean...would you please explain...

Comment: I didn't know you could define nullable parameters like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `EndDate` is nullable, you have to assign a value to it (even null) when you declare it.

```
DateTime? EndDate = null;
```

As for the second error, you should use the property `Value` of the nullable (you should check if it has value first) to get `DateTime` object:

```
if (EndDate.HasValue)
    DataTable dtbl = BIZ.ReportsBIZAdmin.ReportsCityFilter(StartDate, EndDate.Value).Tables[0];
```